# Tomcat gives a warning “The acceptor thread [http-nio-8080-Acceptor] did not stop cleanly” when I shut it down

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat9

I started tomcat in the terminal and then shut it down by using "catalina.sh stop". The console showed these contents. This problem makes me spend 10 more seconds every time restart Tomcat.

```
/Users/matrix/Tomact/apache-tomcat-9.0.74/bin/catalina.sh run
[2023-04-23 08:52:16,965] Artifact demo:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.539 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.74
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 13 2023 08:10:39 UTC
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.74.0
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            13.2.1
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_361.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_361-b09
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/matrix/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/tomcat/afa48016-c355-45c8-95a5-690d57a1db28
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/matrix/Tomact/apache-tomcat-9.0.74
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/matrix/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/tomcat/afa48016-c355-45c8-95a5-690d57a1db28/conf/logging.properties
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Duser.language=en
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Duser.region=CA
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/Users/matrix/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/tomcat/afa48016-c355-45c8-95a5-690d57a1db28/jmxremote.password
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/Users/matrix/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/tomcat/afa48016-c355-45c8-95a5-690d57a1db28/jmxremote.access
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/matrix/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/tomcat/afa48016-c355-45c8-95a5-690d57a1db28
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/matrix/Tomact/apache-tomcat-9.0.74
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/matrix/Tomact/apache-tomcat-9.0.74/temp
23-Apr-2023 20:52:17.549 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/matrix/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
23-Apr-2023 20:52:18.002 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Apr-2023 20:52:18.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [660] milliseconds
23-Apr-2023 20:52:18.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
23-Apr-2023 20:52:18.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.74]
23-Apr-2023 20:52:18.082 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Apr-2023 20:52:18.090 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [51] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2023-04-23 08:52:18,565] Artifact demo:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
23-Apr-2023 20:52:19.634 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[2023-04-23 08:52:20,677] Artifact demo:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2023-04-23 08:52:20,677] Artifact demo:war exploded: Deploy took 2,112 milliseconds
/Users/matrix/Tomact/apache-tomcat-9.0.74/bin/catalina.sh stop
23-Apr-2023 20:52:25.735 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
23-Apr-2023 20:52:25.736 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Apr-2023 20:52:26.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
23-Apr-2023 20:52:26.762 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Apr-2023 20:52:36.763 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.stop The acceptor thread [http-nio-8080-Acceptor] did not stop cleanly
23-Apr-2023 20:52:36.768 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Disconnected from server
```

I tried Google but there were no similar results. I restarted the device, reinstalled, used homebrew and the official compressed package. But both version 9 and 10 had similar problems.
Has anyone encountered the similar problem? Is there any way to solve this problem, let me know the specific location where the Acceptor thread runs, give me some guidance on how to troubleshoot related thread issues.
I look forward to and appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Acceptor.java:
/**
* Signals the Acceptor to stop, waiting at most 10 seconds for the stop to
* complete before returning. If the stop does not complete in that time a
* warning will be logged.
*
* @deprecated This method will be removed in Tomcat 10.1.x onwards.
*             Use {@link #stop(int)} instead.
*/
@Deprecated
public void stop() {
stop(10);
}

```
/**
 * Signals the Acceptor to stop, optionally waiting for that stop process
 * to complete before returning. If a wait is requested and the stop does
 * not complete in that time a warning will be logged.
 *
 * @param waitSeconds The time to wait in seconds. Use a value less than
 *                    zero for no wait.
 */
public void stop(int waitSeconds) {
    stopCalled = true;
    if (waitSeconds > 0) {
        try {
            if (!stopLatch.await(waitSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
               log.warn(sm.getString("acceptor.stop.fail", getThreadName()));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.warn(sm.getString("acceptor.stop.interrupted", getThreadName()), e);
        }
    }
}
```

when you shutdown the tomcat,then the Acceptor exeucte stop()->stop(10).
In the stop(10), if tomcat not stoped after 10s,it will print the warn log.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand how this warning is generated, but is there any way to see what caused the Acceptor did not stop immediately? The 10-second wait every time I restart the project is long.

Comment: Are there some requests which is running ,when you  shutdown it.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I finally find the reason, ClashX system proxy...no wonder I couldn't find any same problem on Google.